# keep increasing or decreasing css "left" value on mouseover

Tags: jquery, css, slider

This is very similar to Netflix's gallery slider. on mousing over the arrows i would like to move div#galleryImages to left or right by increasing or decreasing its left property and keep increasing until i mouse out. essentially this is what I want to do, but I am not sure how:

```
    $(".goRight").mouseover(function() {
        $("galleryImages").css('left', keep decreasing)  
    }

    $(".goRight").mouseover(function() {
        $("galleryImages").css('left', keep increasing)
    }
```

thank you, and here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/exxDW/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You applied increasing and decreasing to .goRight class. I think one should be .goLeft

```
var pos = 400;

$(".goRight").mouseover(function() {
    pos+=20;
    $("galleryImages").css('left', pos)  
}

$(".goLeft").mouseover(function() {
    pos-=20;
    $("galleryImages").css('left', pos)
}
```

Comment: when you hover over the arrows it just increases it once. but it does not continuously increase or decreases: http://jsfiddle.net/exxDW/9/

Comment: Mouseover is fired once if you take your mouse out and enter again it will decreas again. Try this by move mouse on left and right http://jsfiddle.net/exxDW/11/